# Why is every scalar product equivalent to the Standard Scalar Product on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I recently encountered the following claim:

> Consider  $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with an arbitrary scalar product. By choosing an orthonormal basis we may assume that the given scalar product is the Standard Scalar Product.

I do not see why this should be the case. Could you explain?

Comment: Because the matrix of a (positive definite) scalar product in an orthonormal basis is the identity matrix. And because apparently your problem is invariant under change of basis.

Comment: For a precise answer you have to understand what equivalent means. Certainly ther are many inner products on the plane: $a$ times the usual inner product is also an inner product for any $a>0$. Here equivalent is supposed to mean there exists a linear map $T$ which is bijective and takes the usual inner product to the given inner product: $ \langle x, y \rangle'=\langle Tx, Ty \rangle$ where the inner product on the left is the given one and the one on the right is the Euclidean inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing an othonormal basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$, if you take two vectors $v$ and $w$, you can write them as$$v=a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n\text{ and }w=b_1e_1+\cdots+b_ne_n.$$And then$$\langle v,w\rangle=\langle a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n,b_1e_1+\cdots+b_ne_n\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k,$$as with the standard inner product and the standard basis.